# Cauchy problem for the heat equation

Tags: heat-equation, cauchy-problem

I need to find the solution of the Cauchy problem for the heat equation :

$$ 
U_t = U_{xx} + 3t²
$$

where $U(x,0) = sin(x)$

I would appreciate any help

Thanks in advance